# html href with multiple pages and sidebars on flexdashboard

Tags: html, r-markdown, href, sidebar, flexdashboard

I have a query regarding the use of html to link parts of a page to a sidebar. I have managed to do this with one page on a flexdashboard rmd. See example code below:

```
---
title: "My multi-page multi-sidebar href html problem"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
    df_print: paged
---
<style type="text/css">
  body{
  font-family: bahnschrift;
}
</style>

IRIS {data-orientation=rows}
======================= 


Sidebar-iris {.sidebar}
-------------
<br>


### My Iris sidebar 



<font size='-1'>
<ul>
<li><a href="#row-3">Summary</a></li>
<li><a href="#row-5">Head of table</a></li>
<li><a href="#row-7">Plot</a></li>
</li></ul></font size>
</p>


Row {data-height=30}
----------------------------------------------------

<font size = '6'><span style="color: #0073B7;">**My IRIS Page**</font size>

Row {data-height=100}
----------------------------------------------------


Row {data-height=30}
----------------------------------------------------

<font size = '4'><span style="color: #0073B7;">*Information part 1**</font size>

Row {data-height=500 .tabset .tabset-fade}
----------------------------------------------------


`{r}
summary(iris)
`

Row {data-height=30}
----------------------------------------------------

<font size = '4'><span style="color: #0073B7;">**Information Part 2**</font size>

Row {data-height=500 .tabset .tabset-fade}
----------------------------------------------------

`{r}
head(iris)
`

Row {data-height=30}
----------------------------------------------------

<font size = '4'><span style="color: #0073B7;">**information Part 3**</font size>

Row {data-height=500 .tabset .tabset-fade}
----------------------------------------------------

`{r}
plot(iris)
`
```

**To note in the above snippet the R chunks need three tick marks but formatting wasn't allowing for it on Stack Overflow (not too sure why)**

When you knit this rmd, you land on the Iris page, and the components of the sidebar roughly work to take you to the desired section based on the row id. We do this using href. My problems arises when adding a second page to the dashboard, see below code:

```
---
title: "My multi-page multi-sidebar href html problem"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
    df_print: paged
---
<style type="text/css">
  body{
  font-family: bahnschrift;
}
</style>

IRIS {data-orientation=rows}
======================= 


Sidebar-iris {.sidebar}
-------------
<br>


### My Iris sidebar 



<font size='-1'>
<ul>
<li><a href="#row-3">Summary</a></li>
<li><a href="#row-5">Head of table</a></li>
<li><a href="#row-7">Plot</a></li>
</li></ul></font size>
</p>


Row {data-height=30}
----------------------------------------------------

<font size = '6'><span style="color: #0073B7;">**My IRIS Page**</font size>

Row {data-height=100}
----------------------------------------------------


Row {data-height=30}
----------------------------------------------------

<font size = '4'><span style="color: #0073B7;">*Information part 1**</font size>

Row {data-height=500 .tabset .tabset-fade}
----------------------------------------------------


`{r}
summary(iris)
`

Row {data-height=30}
----------------------------------------------------

<font size = '4'><span style="color: #0073B7;">**Information Part 2**</font size>

Row {data-height=500 .tabset .tabset-fade}
----------------------------------------------------

`{r}
head(iris)
`


Row {data-height=30}
----------------------------------------------------

<font size = '4'><span style="color: #0073B7;">**information Part 3**</font size>

Row {data-height=500 .tabset .tabset-fade}
----------------------------------------------------

`{r}
plot(iris)
`


Cars {data-orientation=rows}
======================= 


Sidebar-cars {.sidebar}
-------------
<br>


### My Cars sidebar 



<font size='-1'>
<ul>
<li><a href="#row-10">Summary</a></li>
<li><a href="#row-12">Head of table</a></li>
<li><a href="#row-14">Plot</a></li>
</li></ul></font size>
</p>


Row {data-height=30}
----------------------------------------------------

<font size = '6'><span style="color: #0073B7;">**My Cars Page**</font size>

Row {data-height=100}
----------------------------------------------------


Row {data-height=30}
----------------------------------------------------

<font size = '4'><span style="color: #0073B7;">*Information part 1**</font size>

Row {data-height=500 .tabset .tabset-fade}
----------------------------------------------------


`{r}
summary(cars)
`

Row {data-height=30}
----------------------------------------------------

<font size = '4'><span style="color: #0073B7;">**Information Part 2**</font size>

Row {data-height=500 .tabset .tabset-fade}
----------------------------------------------------

`{r}
head(cars)
`


Row {data-height=30}
----------------------------------------------------

<font size = '4'><span style="color: #0073B7;">**information Part 3**</font size>

Row {data-height=500 .tabset .tabset-fade}
----------------------------------------------------

`{r}
plot(cars)

`
```

When you knit this dashboard, again you land on the Iris page. The sidebar works as usual. When you switch to the second page Cars, everything renders appropriately. However, when you use the cars sidebar is the same desired way, the user is sent back to page Iris. This is despite the cars sidebar using href linking to the appropriate row id on the cars page. I've inspected the elements of the rmd and there was no conflicting id's. I'm not sure whether it is a problem with the pages themselves, but maybe it can be bypassed.

I have tried using two child rmd's but this does not work.

Not too familiar with html so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that the `<font>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) for many, many years.

Comment: Cheers @Rob, makes no difference as all this code is obsolete at the moment. Thanks for your help!